# Arrays and implicit-lifetime object creation

Tags: c++, arrays, object-lifetime

Some types are defined by standard as implicit-lifetime types, and arrays are among them.
Some functions implicitly create objects with implicit-lifetime (malloc etc are among them),
with a list of operations that implicitly create objects with implicit lifetime, found here. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object (I hope it is correct, but for the rest of the question let's assume that `new` works as `malloc` in this case for implicit object creation purposes).

What does it mean to *implicitly create an array* if it doesn't create its elements? Does it mean that

```
T* implicit_array = reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * count, std::align_val_t{alignof(T)}) );
```

produces implicit_array object that is suitable for pointer arithmetic in, namely provides valid storage for elements of type T to be constructed using placement new later?
Does it mean that `new (implicit_array + i) T{...}` is a well defined operation, even though, by the standard, `implicit_array + i` is not necessarily defined? https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-3.2.

Or it means that

```
std::byte* memory = 
    reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * capacity, std::align_val_t{alignof(T)}));
new (memory) T{args1 ...}
// build more objects
new  (memory + (k-1)*sizeof(T) ) T{args_k ...} 
T* implicit_array = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(memory) ); // does it produce array of k elements?
```

treats `implicit_array` as an array with k elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to allocate the storage for the array, first, then construct the elements later. A closely related note in [expr.new/15](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#15) specifically mentions "*the common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed*".

The posted code mostly follows the proper allocate-then-construct sequence, except the `reinterpret_cast` is not safe and is, in fact, not necessary. The conversion from the `void *` returned in the allocation step to the typed `T *` is done by the placement `new` operator at construction time, instead.

```
void *alloc_array(size_t cnt)
{
    return ::operator new(sizeof(T) * cnt, std::align_val_t{alignof(T)});
}

T *construct_array(void *buf, size_t cnt)
{
    T *arr = new(buf) T {...}, *p = arr;
    for(int i = 1; i < cnt; i++)
        p = new(p + 1) T {...};
    return arr;
}

void destruct_array(T *arr, size_t cnt)
{
    for(int i = cnt; i--; )
        arr[i].~T();
}

void free_array(void *buf, size_t cnt)
{
    ::operator delete(buf, sizeof(T) * cnt, std::align_val_t{alignof(T)});
}
```

Sample usage:

```
    void *buf = alloc_array(cnt);
    T *arr = construct_array(buf, cnt);

    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        T &ob = arr[i]; /* ... */

    destruct_array(arr, cnt);
    free_array(buf, cnt);
```

Comment: `p = new(p + 1) T {...}` Is this line valid (by the standard or is it UB)? Isn't p a pointer to single element of type T and not array element? `T *arr = new(buf) T {...}` does not create an array, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Also, what makes `reinterpret_cast` not safe?
As far as I am aware, since arrays are defined to be implicit lifetime objects by the last standard, `(T*)(::operator new (...) )` just like (T*) malloc (... )` should implicitly construct an array, provided that subsequent actions give it defined behavior. Are not (T*) and reinterpret_cast<T*> equivalent?

Comment: @RazielMagius That `arr` is a pointer to the first element of the array, and `arr == &arr[0]` is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @RazielMagius The cast is not safe because it produces a `T *` to something that is not a `T` object (yet) at that point, and attempts to use that pointer as a `T *` may result in UB. It is, indeeed, a legal cast by the language rules, and it will result in the same value of the pointer in the end, though the formal argument is more convoluted. Basically, `reinterpret_cast` translates to `static_cast` ([expr.reinterpret_cast/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)) which ends up copying the pointer value ([expr.static.cast/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13))...

Comment: ...which matches the unchanged pointer that placement new returns ([new.delete.placement/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.placement#5)). But casting it upfront is too early, and is not necessary. Both the standard example ([new.delete.placement/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.placement#4)) and the c++faq ones ([1](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#memory-pools)) use the two step allocation+construction, without any explicit casts.

Comment: I am not sure, however according to this <https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#12>, I think creating an array using `T* implicit_array = reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * count, std::align_val_t{alignof(T)}) )` should be fine. As far as I am aware, `malloc` and `new` both construct objects with implicit lifetime.

Comment: Both examples do no create arrays, but single objects. And while `&p[0]` and `p` are equal, if we use `p[1]` and `q = new (p+1)  T{...}` do not need to be equal in general, even if `p` is an array, which I believe is not the case as `new (p) T{...}` does not create an array, but single object.  And even if `p` was an array, in general, they do not have to be equal - otherwise `std::launder` would not be required.

Comment: @RazielMagius 1) Neither `malloc` nor this `new` overload create "*objects*". They only allocate *storage* where objects will be created later. This distinction is specifically made in [basic.life/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6): "*before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated ...*".  2) `p == &p[0]` and `p + 1 == &p[1]` by definition. 3) `std::launder` is not needed here, and it would apply to the raw pointer anyway, see e.g. "*case 3*" in the bottom example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).

Comment: Please see the example in https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#12 and the comments to it. _"The call to std​::​malloc implicitly creates an object of type X and its subobjects a and b, and returns a pointer to that X object"_. Also, please see
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html which I believe is a part of standard now (at least parts of it).

Comment: @RazielMagius One paragraph up has this important caveat: "***if*** *that value would result in the program having defined behavior. If no such pointer value would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined*". Add a constructor to that `struct`, or a virtual destructor, and the behavior is no longer defined, so the example is about a very special case. Anyway, this is drifting into questions about allocation, lifetime, launder etc, not really related to my answer or the original question as posed.

Comment: My question was what is the meaning of "implicit-lifetime" for arrays.
Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime and implicit-lifetime. Arrays are clearly one of those. 
Also  "_Note that if a subobject of an implicitly created object is not of an implicit-lifetime type, its lifetime does not begin implicitly._"

Comment: PS: Any question about implicit-lifetime is implicitly a question about allocation, lifetime, (sometimes) launder, and (sometimes) memmove (or memcpy) as it is not relevant in any other contexts.

Comment: As for launder part - I did not say that you need to launder in your example. What I said, that in general, the results of the expressions `q = new (p+1) T{...}` and `p+1` do not need to be equal in general.

Comment: @RazielMagius 1) As stated in the linked page (and [basic.life](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life)), an array is implicitly created iff its element type is i.e. it has *vacuous initialization*. But again, my answer (and your original question) is about the general case of an arbitrary type `T` without additional assumptions. 2) The return value of `new (p) T{...}` *is* equal to `p` when using the global or default operator ([new.delete.placement](https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.placement) "*Returns: ptr*"), otherwise if you provide a class override then it's your choice what it returns.

Comment: Arrays are implicit-lifetime types, by the standard, without reference to their type. Please see https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-9.
_Scalar types, implicit-lifetime class types ([class.prop]), array types, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called implicit-lifetime types._

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that this one should be valid code:
`(T(*)[])::operator new(sizeof(T) * count, std::align_val_t{ alignof(T) })` as it returns a pointer to an array (which is implicitly constructed type), while `(T*)::operator new(... )` returns a pointer to first element of the array, which is not implicitly constructed itself. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @RazielMagius From the previously linked [basic.life/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1): "*A variable is said to have vacuous initialization if it is default-initialized and*, ***if it is*** *of class type or a (possibly multi-dimensional)* ***array thereof***, *that class type has a trivial default constructor. The lifetime of an object of type T begins when: (1.1) ... and (1.2) its initialization (if any) is complete (* ***including vacuous*** *initialization)*". That said, all this may be better suited for another question than random comments so I think I'll drop out now.